# Build .NET Applications with Docker possible ?

Tags: .net, windows, docker, msbuild, server

I read allot about Docker and i can see that Microsoft now can create Docker Containers based on Hyper V on Windows Server 2016 so i was thinking if it would be possible to create containers including OS and the build tools needed to compile .NET apps ? How much can such container include ? Can it include regular Windows Apps and can one interact with the UI of such container ?

I think docker containers would be much lower footprint on our environment than spawning many VM.

donnib

Comment: ASP.NET Core was built with Docker in mind. So why not check that out?

Comment: Any ideas about this ? I am still interested to know if this is possible. I can see that MS has released the nanoserver for windows 10 but can it build regular .NET apps ?